# How to determine the amount of free memory when running a google cloud function?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

When running a google cloud function the memory size can be set (https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/configuring/memory).

If I select `512MB`, how can I determine how much of that 512MB is free after loading my libraries ? So for example - if I need to load and process data that's 12MB in size, and it takes 500MB to load my libraries, I won't have enough memory. Whereas if it takes 250MB to load my libraries I probably will have enough memory.

I'm using Python, if there's something that I can output to a log and then inspect in the gcp logs explorer that would be useful

Answer (score 3):

You can use [**psutil virtual_memory**](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#psutil.virtual_memory) to determine how much memory is used and how much is available.

But you will need to install that library using `pip install psutil`.

As python runtime is now recently available but for node js one you can use following to get the available memory:

```
const freeMemory = process.memoryUsage();
```

Reference for this : [Node.js process.memoryUsage() Method](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/node-js-process-memoryusage-method/amp/)

Comment: Have you verified that works in Cloud Functions and for gen1 and gen2?

Comment: @John Hanley Yes